# How can I perform this update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Table A which contains columns PK and Code.
I have Table B which contains columns PK, Data, Code, and FK.
The number of duplicate records with the same Data and Code in Table B is equal to the number of duplicate records with the same Code in Table A.

I want to update FK in Table B so that each duplicate record (same Data and same Code) points to the unique PK in Table A based on matching Code in Table A and Table B.

Example:

```
|Table A
| PK         |         Code| 
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          |        v665 |
| 2          |        v665 |
| 3          |        v665 |   
| 4          |        v998 |
| 5          |         y69 |
| 6          |         y69 |

Table B
| PK | Data        | Code | FK |
|:---|------------:|:----:|---:|
| 1  |   some info | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 1
| 2  |   some info | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 2
| 3  |   some info | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 3
| 4  |   important | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 1
| 5  |   important | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 2
| 6  |   important | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 3
| 7  |  more stuff | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 1
| 8  |  more stuff | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 2
| 9  |  more stuff | v665 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 3
| 10 |   some data | v998 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 4
| 11 |   some more | v998 |    | <- should be updated to Table A PK 4
```

I have tried many solutions, including nested cursors, but haven't been able to produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by using the `row_number` window function to generate a unique value that you can use to join on:

```
update b
   set b.fk = a.pk
  from (select b.*,
               row_number() over (partition by b.code, b.data order by b.pk) as rn
          from TableB b) b
  join (select a.*,
               row_number() over (partition by a.code order by a.pk) as rn
          from TableA a) a
    on a.code = b.code
   and a.rn = b.rn
```

Comment: Wow! Nice query. I have a hard time wrapping my head around it though. Could you explain a bit how it works?

Comment: The key to understanding the update statement is understanding the `row_number` window function.  You can read about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx. Once that is a bit clearer, execute the 2 subqueries individually and observe how the `rn` values are generated. You'll notice that for each logical grouping (`code` in table `A`, and `(code, data)` in table `B` -- see `partition by` clauses), `row_number` will uniquely number each row within those groups.  That unique number per logical group is then used as part of the join condition to match the rows correctly.